# Auto-configuration of mysql in spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to auto-configure mysql in spring boot application 1.4.1 (Most recent is 1.4.2, but that version is not working at all).  I added the datasource to the application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/transcoder
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=pass
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

And defined the main application

```
package transcoder;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class TranscoderSpringApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TranscoderSpringApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

I have a model:

```
package transcoder.datasource.model;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.NonNull;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;

@Data
@Entity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class VideoFile implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5632175181967653240L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    @NonNull
    @NotNull
    @Column(nullable=false)
    private String filename;
}
```

and a repository:

```
package transcoder.datasource.repository;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

import nl.csdigitalmedia.transcoder.datasource.model.VideoFile;

public interface VideoFileRepository extends CrudRepository<VideoFile, Integer> {
    List<VideoFile> findByFilename(String filename);
}
```

But when I start the application it gives

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Method mvcConversionService in org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport required a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' in your configuration.
```

Everything I googled says the configuration should work.

Update (pom.xml):

```
    <name>transcoder-spring</name>
    <description>Spring REST service for transcoding videos</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-integration</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.restdocs</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-restdocs-mockmvc</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

In the report:

```
   CacheAutoConfiguration.CacheManagerJpaDependencyConfiguration did not match
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean' (OnClassCondition)
      - Ancestor org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.CacheAutoConfiguration did not match (ConditionEvaluationReport.AncestorsMatchedCondition)

   HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration did not match
          - @ConditionalOnClass found required classes 'org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean', 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement', 'javax.persistence.EntityManager' (OnClassCondition)
          - HibernateEntityManager did not find classes 'org.hibernate.ejb.HibernateEntityManager', 'org.hibernate.jpa.HibernateEntityManager' (HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.HibernateEntityManagerCondition)
```

Comment: Have you actually looked at the message? It is complaining about the `entityManagerFactory` NOT about your `DataSource`. Make sure that you have all the needed dependencies.

Comment: I expected the entityManagerFactory be auto-generated.

Comment: It will but apparently that fails either due to missing/wrong configuration or jars. Start with `--debug` which should give you the stack trace and thus more information on what is wrong.

Comment: Attach the contents of your pom.

Comment: If this is all the code you have it should all work, can you run your app with the `--debug` option and attach the auto configuration report? You can find it in the log by searching for "AUTO-CONFIGURATION REPORT", if it scrolls past too fast.

Comment: Solved it: Set hibernate version to 5.2.5.Final, exclude hibernate-entitymanager from spring-boot-starter-data-jpa. This causes a problem with javassisst so add org.javassist.javassist and set javassist.version to 3.21.0-GA.